# Facebook page tab iframe app not working

Tags: facebook, iframe

So I've followed the instructions in all the other questions.

I did this:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL

Now i just get a blank page when i click the page tab link (from admin login or not as admin). it goes to facebook.com/mypage/app_{my_id} as expected but does nothing.

[image]

All the links https or not https WORK FINE! Even on the page settings/apps i can click "goto app" and it works fine!

The page tab settings in my application settings do not point to the apps.facebook.com/myapp URL as suggested by another thread. It is NOT setup as a FBML page.

Once and a while I get

```
App Temporarily Unavailable
Parse errors:
FBML Error (line 6): illegal tag "body"
```

however, this is an iframe app, not an FBML app.

Driving me crazy, all the other questions here have no proper solution for this.

Is there a solution? I don't really have code to post, as it works fine and dandy accessing the app from any means except the page tab option. That is, the app works fine as a normal iframe app, it's just the page-tab URL is not making the last step.

Here is the app settings. It is clearly not set to FBML.

[image]

Comment: Yet another downvote with no explanation. haters.

Comment: I would be 99% sure your app *is* set up as an FBML app either in the canvas settings in the advanced tab, or in the page tab settings

Comment: Yeah I'd consider adding an anonymised screenshot of the app config if you're completely sure this isn't an FBML app.

Comment: @lgy %100 NOT configured as an FBML app in the applicaion config. i have heard that legacy application may have bugs. this app is probably 4 years old+ I've no idea.

Comment: I don't know why this keeps getting voted down. I'm being pretty specific: iframe app is being interpreted incorrectly. I can't show you FB server code =)

Comment: You're funny, two Facebook employees replied to you. >.<

Comment: @igy "or in the page tab settings"  I don't see any control over rendering in the page tab application settings. Is there somewhere else?

Comment: See my answer below; there's a migration setting which controls this, i was incorrect when i said it was in the page tab settings

Comment: thanks, it's getting closer, but seems to be suffering from an HTTPS page tab transition bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm almost 100% sure this is the FBML settings, check *both* of these settings for the app are not set to FBML - unless you can give us the App ID to check, nobody can give an absolutely 100% sure answer

1) On the 'advanced' tab, the setting for 'canvas mode' - this will not appear for apps created after March 2011

[image: Screenshot of the setting]

2) There was a setting for 'Page Tab iframe' in the 'Migrations' setting of the Advanced Tab. This controls whether or not FBML is used with the page tabs of your app - if set to disabled, the app is still using FBML for its page tabs

[image: Screenshot of the setting]

You can also check second setting via the API, for my example app there, the canvas setting can be retrieved via a call to /APPLICATION_ID/?fields=migrations&access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN

The return value is a structure of the migrations the app can set and their values:

```
{
  "migrations": {
    "secure_stream_urls": false, 
    "expiring_offline_access_tokens": false, 
    "december_rollup": false, 
    "page_tab_iframe": false, 
    //[ SNIPPED OTHER MIGRATIONS ]
  }, 
  "id": " // SNIPPED APP ID", 
  "type": "application"
}
```

Comment: BTW both of those screenshots are from today, on regular apps, both of which predate the FBML app deprecation in March 2011

Comment: The migrations seemed to work... But if I'm not a secure browsing user, the page-tab errors out. Exactly Like this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/362855400443900 if I manually add https or change my security settings to secure, works fine.

Comment: Is the 'page tab URL' value you're using relative or absolute? I believe both were supported at one point, try setting it as absolute if it's relative - i'm not sure of the status of that bug report

Comment: The URL is absolute. Guess I will have to wait on the FB bug.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem, the problem was that I had an secure URL (https) in both the canvas and secure canvas. On unsecured connections, the empty rectangle was a result. Both an secure (https) and unsecured (http) URL is required.