# Tab App Link not working correctly

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-page

So I found this article, but it doesn't really answer my issue... ([Facebook page tab iframe app not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777511/facebook-page-tab-iframe-app-not-working))

I have successfully added the tab to my page and it shows up correctly. The problem is for some reason the tab links to https://www.facebook.com/MyPage/app_XXXXXXXXXX. When you click this link it just opens a blank canvas page.

However when I use the link provided in my app settings https://apps.facebook.com/MyAppName the page loads just fine.

According to the other articles I've found (which are OLD) there are setting issues between iFrame & FBML, but this is a BRAND NEW app that I just created yesterday (2013, waaaay after the FBML change).

Any ideas on how to make the app link go to the correct page?

Answer (score -1):

https://raw.github.com/mozillahispano/asksumo-fb/master/doc/2install.png

maybe problem with config. app. I will share you a image with some config of my facebook app.
i hope to help you.

Comment: BLESS YOU!!!! THANK YOU!!!! It was my config. Facebook doesn't always do a good job explaining fields. It's working now.